# "For" loop for CubeFields in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do a loop to EnableMultiplePageItems for all cubefields.  So I have to resort to something like this.

```
Sub MultipleFilter()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(1).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(2).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(3).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(4).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(5).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(6).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(7).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(8).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(9).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(10).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(11).EnableMultiplePageItems = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193066.aspx

```
Dim objCubeFld 
For Each objCubeFld In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields 
     objCubeFld.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
Next objCubeFld
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tim.  The code you provided did not seem to work.  I get run-time error 1004 "Application-defined or object defined error".
 
Shouldn't "Dim objCubFld" be followed by "as" something?  I tried "as CubeField" and "as CubeFields" and received errors as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `EnableMultiplePageItems` doesn't work for measures.  Looping is pretty much as you'd expect, but you'll want to test the `CubeFieldType` property for each `CubeField` and only enable the property for those with type `xlHierarchy`.

```
Dim cf As CubeField

For Each cf In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").CubeFields
    If cf.CubeFieldType = xlHierarchy Then
        cf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    End If
Next cf
```

For more info: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835244.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823030.aspx